# Hybrid Exchange and failed migration

Tags: office365, exchange-server

We have several users on an Exchange 16 box and several on O365 (most migrated - some new employees). After migrating one user to 365 we noticed anyone still on the 16 server sending to him it goes to his mailbox on that server (not the 365 account). Management console on the 16 server shows his mailbox type as a user and not Office 365 like the other migrated boxes. Should I try to re-migrate it or just delete the old mailbox of the 16 server?

Comment: Nevermind - got there with this: https://www.itpromentor.com/link-aduser-365/